# uploadify keeps giving new session for every upload request

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, uploadify

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3 with [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). I followed these blogs:

- [Using uploadify with Rails 3](http://www.glrzad.com/ruby-on-rails/using-uploadify-with-rails-3/)
- [Rails 3, Paperclip and Uploadify](https://github.com/websymphony/Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify/)

And everything works fine, expect that on my upload_controller it keeps giving me a new session. I can't keep track how many photos have been uploaded by this anonymous user.

```
def create
    @photo = Photo.new(newparams[:photo])
    if @photo.save
      session[:photo_ids] ||= []
      session[:photo_ids] << @photo.id
      render :json => { :result => 'success', :photo => photo_path(@photo) }
    else    
      render :json => { :result => 'failed', :error =>  "Failed to upload the image."}
    end
end
```

I wonder why `session[:photo_ids]` keeps getting nil for every upload request, but other requests using `session[:product_id]` still function as usual.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am facing same issue. I have been using Rails 3.0.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: I resolved this issue with help of [ Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify](https://github.com/websymphony/Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify)

Comment: I used jquery-fileupload instead.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know ruby well enough to give you code but I came across a similar problem with uploadify and C#.  In FF and Chrome (I presume Safari as well) the current session is not sent back by uploadify (it is in IE and everything works ok).  The recommended way around this is to post your session id as part of the uploadify data and then pull the session manually in Ruby.

Depending what you are doing with the session there may be security concerns, but from your description it shouldnt be a problem.